# How to use Meteor's Blaze as a standalone front-end framework?

Tags: meteor, frontend, meteor-blaze

Recently I've been coding with **Meteor**.
And as a front-end developer, I simply love it! The syntax, the simplicity, it is fantastic.

I am now curious how to use **Blaze** standalone, as a front-end framework like Angular. What about routing, ajax calls, and other stuff?

How to get started, and what about the future of the Blaze?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Blaze & Spacebars](https://www.meteor.com/blaze) depend on 'reactive' data sources. It'd be hard to just include it in your project, as you'd have to deal with [Tracker](https://www.meteor.com/tracker) and everything that comes with it. In a Meteor project, all this is hidden of course (and made super-simple and convenient). I believe as a separate front-end framework, it would introduce much more headache. Blaze also isn't (and is not going to be, hopefully) a full-fledged framework (e.g. no routing, no ajax calls, nothing). It's just simple by default.

Comment: Thank you @Oskar, do you know any similar framework? Cause I really like the simplicity and syntax of Blaze.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at http://meteor.github.io/blaze/

You can use blaze stand alone

However, instead of using

```
<template name="foo"></template>
```

You will use

```
<script type="text/spacebars" name="foo"></script>
```

in your html file

Comment: What Router or Ajax utils can I use with this?

Comment: For ajax, have a look at microjs.com for some micro library